# Create igraph according image

Tags: r, igraph

I need create graph with dataset that looks like this. The code renders a graph that need "sew" together and be something similar to a picture below. Dataframe cannot be changed.

```
df <- data.frame(col0 = "Animals",
col1 = c(NA, "1", "1", "1"),
col2 = c(NA, "3", "3", "3"),
col3 = c(NA, "Cat Dog Wolf", "Cat Dog Wolf", "Cat Dog Wolf"),
col4 = c(NA, "1", "2", "3"),
col5 = c(NA, "Cat", "Dog", "Wolf"),
col6 = c(NA, "Feline", "Canis", "Canis2")) 


sub <-df[!is.na(df$col3),]
df <-df[-c(1), ]
df <-df[c('col6', 'col5')]

df$'new_col' <- paste(df$'col6',df$'col5')
#creating a new col with col5 and col6 info

df <-  rbind(df[4:5,c(1,4)],data.frame('col3'=df[4,6],'new_col'=df[5,6]))
#this is where I get lost when tring get vertex

names(df) <-c('from', 'to')
abc <-union(df$to, df$from)
g <-graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE, vertices = abc)
plot(g, vertex.size = 20, vertex.label.dist = 0.5, vertex.color = c("lightblue","red","green","white"),
edge.arrow.size = 0.5, layout = layout.reingold.tilford(g))
```

[image]

Comment: The table of your data seems unclear.  Please use `dput(df)` and paste the result into your question so that we can get your exact data structure.

Comment: I added normal dataframe

Comment: Do you simply want the graph data frame that will produce that graph, or do you want code that creates the desired graph data frame from your original data?  If the latter,  it is not clear what the rules are for interpreting  the original data.

Comment: Original dataframe cannot be changed, I want code be changed

Comment: @DeividasKiznis ; can you explain the logic of how your dataframe relates to the final plot. If you are treating the dataframe rows as edge lists then you could have an edge from (cat dog wolf) to both (feline cat) and (canis dog) ie first two rows of your data. But where in your dataframe does is an edge indicated from (canis dog) to (canis2 wolf).

Comment: with `rbind` you can add hierarchy and `col3` column is a "top" while the rest two are splitted into feline branch and canis branch